# Reading an R data frame with column of vectors (stored by NetLogo)

Tags: r, netlogo

I'm new to R, and considering its use in my NetLogo work. One of the helpful examples for NetLogo's R extension from Jan Thiele is `datafile-example.netlogo`. Its third function illustrates what to do when ***saving*** a data frame to a file when a column contains vectors: use `I()` to mark that column as class `AsIs`. Here is code based on that example.

```
crt 30 [ set xcor random-xcor
         set ycor random-ycor
         set test (list random 10 random 20 random 30 random 40 ) ]
(r:putagentdf "ag" turtles "who" "xcor" "ycor" "test" )
r:eval "ag$test <- I(ag$test)"
r:eval (word "write.table(ag , sep=';', file='" path "')" )
```

There is no example for ***reading*** that data back into R, and I can't figure out how to do it.

The cells of the data frame's column are numeric vectors in R.

```
> str(Glob)
'data.frame':   30 obs. of  4 variables:
$ who : num  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ...
$ xcor: num  -3.201 -11.507 -9.045 -0.242 4.161 ...
$ ycor: num  2.82 3.86 -5.14 -8.45 8.96 ...
$ test:List of 30
..$ : num  2 6 29 1
..$ : num  6 3 17 17
<snip>
```

But they are saved in the file as vector text input. The two above are thus `c(2, 6, 29, 1)` and `c(6, 3, 17, 17)`.

Thus far, as shown in the code above and below, I've added the `sep` and `stringsAsFactors` options (and also tried unsuccessfully to use `colClasses`).

```
r:eval (word "ag <- read.table(file='" path "', sep=';', stringsAsFactors=FALSE)" )
```

Now the cells of that column are strings.

```
> str(agGlob)
'data.frame':   30 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ who : int  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ...
 $ xcor: num  -3.201 -11.507 -9.045 -0.242 4.161 ...
 $ ycor: num  2.82 3.86 -5.14 -8.45 8.96 ...
 $ test: chr  "c(2, 6, 29, 1)" "c(6, 3, 17, 17)" "c(3, 18, 25, 34)" "c(8, 5, 3, 7)" ...
```

So, the question remains: how to read this data back into R. A second step will be getting it back to NetLogo. Maybe there's no point to reading it into R? (Then why save it from R?)

For that second step, there are a host of specialized `r:put...` commands but nothing other than a vanilla `r:get` command. Although this may be further indication that there's something I'm missing here, it does appear that `r:get` does some sophisticated conversion on lists, yet vectors aren't mentioned in its description, either.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a decent answer, although there still may be something that I'm missing in the intended use of the R extension's functionality.

In addition to the `sep=';'` (in both `write.table` and `read.table`) and `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` options, some post-processing is necessary:

```
let t r:get "lapply(ag$test, function(x) eval(parse(text=x)))"
```

At least I've learned a bit of R.

Comment: Nice job figuring it out. My two cents- your question "Then why save it from R?" is what I would ask, too. I think the "datafile-example" that you were using is mostly demonstrating how to output your analysis/results/data once you have done what you need. I expect that usually you would be doing your work within the R environment rather than writing to file, loading again, etc.

Comment: True; I'm thus looking forward to learning RNetLogo. We're also still left with a second-level question: Why save a vector as an element in a data frame? Once again, I feel the answer is that I'm still early in using R as part of NetLogo.